# compile css on the fly with node-sass

Tags: node-sass

i'm trying to build an on-the-fly compiler for my scss files.
The logic is:
 - when the page ask node or .css file
 - look wich subdomain is calling
 - compile the css with:

```
var result = sass.renderSync({
    file: org+'/css/sass/main.scss',
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
});
return res.send(result.css);
```

all is working "fine" as i got my result.css (object) with all the compiled stylesheet but.. it's not being loaded from the browser!

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed node-sass module to compile the scss files, cleancss to minimize and then I fixed the problem setting the header before sending the results.

```
    var result = sass.renderSync({
        file: org+'/css/sass/main.scss'
    });
    result = new cleancss().minify(result.css);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/css');
    return res.send(result.styles);
```